# How to load a local PDF into webView?

Tags: android, kotlin, scoped-storage

I am using ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument() to open a PDF.
I get its uri.

But how can I load it into a webView component?
I'm using SDK 33.

[image: Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  It's a webview, it displays HTML, not PDF.  It doesn't have a PDF viewing mode.  There are some hacks out there where you upload the file to google docs or similar sites then open a webview to that site, but the webview won't be able to display a local pdf.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

webView?.loadUrl(uri.patch!!);

this example works for me
[Load Pdf webview](https://djangocas.dev/blog/android/various-ways-to-load-pdf-in-android-webview/)